# Hbase doesn't work well with spark-submit

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hbase, spark-submit

I have an app that does some work and at the end it needs to read some file from hdfs and store it into hbase. The app runs when using master local with no issue using apache spark, but when I run it using spark-submit it doesn't work anymore,I get a fail.

The command line code is :

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0 pathjar
```

And the error that I get is:

```
Java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:3207)
at utils.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:63)
at utils.HBaseClient.exists(HBaseClient.java:224)
at utils.HBaseUtils.createTable(HBaseUtils.java:201)
at utils.HBaseUtils.execute(HBaseUtils.java:86)
at Query1.getResponse(Query1.java:43)
at Main.main(Main.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create  interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSource Is the hadoop compatibility jar on the classpath?
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilitySingletonFactory.getInstance(CompatibilitySingletonFactory.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeper.<init>(MetricsZooKeeper.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.<init>(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:181)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.<init>(ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.java:43)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:945)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:721)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSource: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilitySingletonFactory.getInstance(CompatibilitySingletonFactory.java:59)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MetricsInfoImpl from class org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DynamicMetricsRegistry
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DynamicMetricsRegistry.newGauge(DynamicMetricsRegistry.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.java:59)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
... 39 more
Creating table...
java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:240)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:218)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(HBaseAdmin.java:3207)
at utils.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:63)
at utils.HBaseClient.createTable(HBaseClient.java:87)
at utils.HBaseUtils.createTable(HBaseUtils.java:203)
at utils.HBaseUtils.execute(HBaseUtils.java:86)
at Query1.getResponse(Query1.java:43)
at Main.main(Main.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:238)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create  interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSource Is the hadoop compatibility jar on the classpath?
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilitySingletonFactory.getInstance(CompatibilitySingletonFactory.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeper.<init>(MetricsZooKeeper.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.<init>(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:143)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:181)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.<init>(ZooKeeperKeepAliveConnection.java:43)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveZooKeeperWatcher(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getClusterId(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.retrieveClusterId(ConnectionManager.java:945)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(ConnectionManager.java:721)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSource: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.CompatibilitySingletonFactory.getInstance(CompatibilitySingletonFactory.java:59)
... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.MetricsException: Metrics source ZooKeeper,sub=ZOOKEEPER already exists!
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.newSourceName(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.sourceName(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:117)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.register(MetricsSystemImpl.java:229)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.BaseSourceImpl.<init>(BaseSourceImpl.java:115)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.java:56)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsZooKeeperSourceImpl.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
... 39 more
```

Hope someone can explain me what's the probblem, thanks in advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create  interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetricsZooKeeperSource Is the hadoop compatibility jar on the classpath
```

Its clear indication of version mismatch of hadoop jar files.

it is working in `local` from your ide since you have the appropriate jar in your classpath. 
where as cluster or client modes of spark-submit it doesnt.

package all your application dependencies in a single jar which are in your local(since it works) and do a `spark-submit`

How to Debug : you can print all jars in local  like this in 
**scala**

```
def urlsinclasspath(cl: ClassLoader): Array[java.net.URL] = cl match {
      case null => Array()
      case u: java.net.URLClassLoader => u.getURLs() ++ urlses(cl.getParent)
      case _ => urlsinclasspath(cl.getParent)
    }

    val  urls = urlsinclasspath(getClass.getClassLoader).foreach(println)
```

**java** :

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
public static void urlsInClasspath () {

        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();

        for(URL url: urls){
            System.out.println(url.getFile());
        }

   }
```